# Need help geting the Electronic Serial Number (ESN) from a Symbol HandHeld PC

Tags: c#, windows-ce, handheld

I have a Handheld PC (Symbol MC9090) working with Windows CE 5.0 and I need to get the Serial Number (not the UniqueID).

I've tried with the KernelIOControl as suggested in many sites, but it returns the UniqueID, not the ESN.

A co-worker told me to try with the RCM2API32.dll RCM_GetESN, but i do not have the header of the method to import it.

I've tried this but isn't working.

```
    [DllImport("rcm2api32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern string RCM_GetESN(string UID);
```

I couldn't find any manuals or reference sheets on the internet.

Can someone give me a hand on this?

Thanks in advance!

Nico.

-- Edit --

With a test program (BasicResCoords.exe) I can see the handheld's ESN. it uses the same DLL I'm dealing with.

Comment: What isn't working about it? What's it doing/not doing?

Comment: is returning an empty string.

Comment: Solved! i found a library that returns the ESN (and many other data).

search for "Symbol ResourceCoordinator TerminalInfo", some sites has it to download.

Comment: If you solved it, post the answer, don't put it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! i found a library that returns the ESN (and many other data). search for "Symbol ResourceCoordinator TerminalInfo", some sites has it to download.